# $\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$, for $x(t),y(t)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a hopefully simple question. I am guessing that this has been asked before but I wasn't sure how to search for it.

Suppose we have two functions: $x(t)$, $y(t)$.

What is $\frac{dx}{dt}/\frac{dy}{dt}$? And why?

Note that this is not the setup for the standard chain rule (or at least its not obvious to me that it is). I talked to some friends and some of them say "just cancel out the $dt$s." Obviously, $\frac{dx}{dt}$, for example, is just the notation for a limit and not a ratio of numbers and so there is no reason as such that we should be able to "just cancel out."

Working with the limits directly, I can get up to:

$$ \lim_{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{x(t+ \triangle t)-x(t)}{y(t+\triangle t)-y(t)} $$

Thinking in terms of infinitesimals, this "feels" a lot like $dx/dy$ but I don't see any formal reason for why it is.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio you post is a consequence of the following, where we have $f(g(t))$, with $x = f(t)$, $y= g(t)$. Then by the chain-rule,

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dy}\cdot \dfrac{dy}{dt} \iff \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$$

Comment: I think you are using a setup where $y$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ is a function of y? I know the chain rule applies in this situation but this not the setup I had. Am I missing something?

Comment: Both are functions of $t$, but $x$ is also a function of $y$, like in $x = e^{2t + 1}$, $y = 2t + 1$, so by the chain rule, $dx/dt = dx/dy \cdot dy/dt$ $$x' = \underbrace{\frac{d}{dt}(2t + 1)}_{dy/dt}\underbrace{e^{2t+1}}_{dx/dy}$$

Comment: If both are functions of $t$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$, whereas $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}$.

Comment: Both are functions of $t$. My question is precisely that: why is $dy/dx = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ (for example)?

Comment: And my explanation is that it follows from the chain rule. $$dy/dt = (dy/dx)\cdot(dx/dt)$$ Now we solve for $dy/dx$ $$dy/dx = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$$

Comment: We're being invaded, @Amzoti! Time to get our swords out and do battle!

Comment: I feel we are going to need to pull out the lightsabers and the force for these! :-)

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$, the ratio $\frac{dy/dt}{dy/dt}$ has a meaning only when $\frac{dx}{dt}\neq0$. Let $a$ a point such that $\frac{dx}{dt}(a)\neq0$. If, in addition, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is continuous at $a$ (quite frequent situation), then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ has a constant sign on a small interval around $a$, hence $x$ is 1-1 on this interval. This allows us to write $t$ as a function of $x$ so $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me what $$\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$$ is, my answer is simple: it is $\frac{x'(t)}{y'(t)}$. As your friends say, $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the operator that acts as the derivative (with respect to $t$). 
All other interpretations require additional assumptions: if you assume that $t$ can be expressed as a differentiable function of $x$, then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx},
$$
and if $t=t(x)$ is invertible, then $\frac{dt}{dx} = \left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^{-1}$, and therefore
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^{-1}.
$$
But you need to know that you can invert a function, at least.

Your idea about taking a limit as $\Delta t \to 0$ is very dangerous, since $y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)$ also for $\Delta t \neq 0$, and you are not allowed to divide by zero. This is the popular but *wrong* proof of the chain rule.

Comment: We're working with $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$, not $dy/dx$.

Comment: Oh my God, can't you just swap $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Siminore: Thanks for the reply. The limit expression is just based on the definitions of $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ (this is where the $\triangle t \to 0$ comes from). I can take the limit operator out because the limit defined by $dy/dt$ exists by assumption.

Comment: Good answer, although I think you mean that $x(t)$ has to be invertible (otherwise $t(x)$ doesn't make sense).

Comment: Well, actually, $dt/dx$ implies that $t$ is a function of $x$. If this function can be inverted as $x=x(t)$, then you can apply the rule to differentiate the inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

The formal reason for why $$\lim_{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{x(t+ \triangle t)-x(t)}{y(t+\triangle t)-y(t)} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ is because the very definition of dy/dt is
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \lim\limits_{\Delta t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t} $$.

Basically,
$$\lim_{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{x(t+ \triangle t)-x(t)}{y(t+\triangle t)-y(t)} =\lim_{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{\frac{x(t+ \triangle t)-x(t)}{\Delta t}}{\frac{y(t+\triangle t)-y(t)}{\Delta t}} =  \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

To clarify the final step,
If we we want to find a tangent line on to a curve where y is a differentiable function of x, then the Chain Rule gives $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$, solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives us $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$

If you want a better way to think about it rather than the $dt$'s cancelling out, think of it this way:
$$ 
\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dt}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot 1 = \frac{dy}{dx}
$$

As for $\frac{dt}{dt} = 1$, even though every one on this site is about to kill me for this, the above expression can be thought of as:

$$
\frac{dt}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{\frac{1}{\infty}}{\frac{1}{\infty}} = \frac{\infty}{\infty} = \frac{1}{1}
$$

## Afterthought

The equation you are trying to prove assumes the relation that you are having fault with.
This is assumed because it is first assumed that both f and g are differentiable functions and that  **y is differentiable with respect to x**. It isn't an algebraic manipulation, but rather an equality made by the construction of the functions themselves.
Since formulation of $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ assumes that $ \frac{dy}{dx}$, the relation is true by construction.

Comment: In the expression after the "Basically", how do you get the last equality? That is my original question. Also, in re-arranging $\frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}$, I guess you are treating these derivatives as ratios? I don't see why this is justified.

Comment: I updated the OP, and in response to the justification of treating them as ratios, you're actually right about it not being justified. Its more of a trick of notation, and there probably is a formal proof of it, but I state that it is only a way to think about it before using it.

I'm actually going to try and justify it using limit laws, but there probably isn't one that I can derive at my level.

Comment: The proof of the standard chain rule you are using assumes that y is a y function of x (as you mention) and x is a function of t. I am considering a setup where y and x are both functions of t. Maybe there is a way to rewrite the my setup in terms of the standard setup (perhaps with some additional assumptions) but they are not obviously the same.

Comment: Of course we assume that, y and x were parameterized as functions of t *assuming dependence on each other*. The expression you are trying to prove assumes mutual dependence, or else it would not make any sense. Infact, it would just be evaluated the quotient rule.

Comment: @user81164 I updated the answer with a definitive answer. I've checked with 3 textbooks, and they all agree, it isn't a manipulation, but instead the formulation of $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ assumes that y is differentiable with respect to x, hence:  $ \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. You are saying if y(t) and x(t) is differentiable, a function y=f(x) exists and is differentiable. If this is the case, we can use the standard chain rule to get dy/dt. I still don't get why f(x) exists and is differentiable? It seems surprising that this would be the case without any additional assumptions (e.g. some invertibility requirement).

Comment: Now that I think about it, if we can invert $y(t)$ to get $t(y)$, then we can get $x$ as a function of $y$, $x(t(y))$. If $t(y)$ is differentiable, the standard chain rule applies. So the question is when will $t(y)$ exist and be differentiable? I guess we can use the inverse function theorem for some sufficient conditions. If $y(t)$ is continuously differentiable and its derivative is not equal to zero, then $t(y)$ will exist and be continuously differentiable. I'm not sure if there are weaker sufficient conditions.

Comment: It exits because we assume it is without prior condition. If it didn't, then the equality would be incorrect.
Then when is a moot point, because we assume it so.